# MultiProcessing Thread Pool Returns Null Result

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

The tup list is a subset of huge dataset. I have been trying to use multithreading to reduce the computing time. But the dfsi list gives null result?

```
dfsi = list[]

tup = [(28075,69),(28075,72),(28075,73),(28075,76),(28075,96),(28075,99), 
(28075,102),(28075,103),(28075,162),(28075,165)]

from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool 

def multi_processing_tuples(sku,ids):
    Q0 = np.percentile(df[((df['sku'] == sku) & (df['ids'] == ids)), 0)
    Q4 = np.percentile(df[((df['sku'] == sku) & (df['ids'] == ids))], 100)
    dfsi.append((sku,ids,Q0,Q4))

pool_size = 5
pool = ThreadPool(pool_size)

for (sku,ids) in tup:
    pool.apply_async(multi_processing_tuples, ((sku,ids),))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

EDIT:

```
dfsi = list[]

tup = [(28075,69),(28075,72),(28075,73),(28075,76),(28075,96),(28075,99), 
(28075,102),(28075,103),(28075,162),(28075,165)]

from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool 

def multi_processing_tuples(sku,ids):
    Q0 = np.percentile(df[((df['sku'] == sku) & (df['ids'] == ids)), 0)
    Q4 = np.percentile(df[((df['sku'] == sku) & (df['ids'] == ids))], 100)
    return(sku,ids,Q0,Q4)

pool_size = 5
pool = ThreadPool(pool_size)

for (sku,ids) in tup:
    dfsi.append(pool.apply_async(multi_processing_tuples, ((sku,ids),)))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

i am getting dfsi output as.

```
[<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x1f707d7d9b0>,
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x1f707d7d748>,
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x1f707d7d710>,
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x1f707d7dda0>,
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x1f707d8e0f0>,
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x1f707d8e358>,
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x1f707d8e320>,
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x1f707d8e6a0>,
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x1f707d936d8>,
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x1f707d93eb8>]
```

how can I see the real output?

Answer (score 0):

When you spawn a new thread, you share the data from your original process, but when you try to alter that data it gets copied. When you close that thread, you are NOT implicitly copying anything back. You need to explicitly return your results and then deal with them in the parent.

```
def multi_processing_tuples(skid):
    sku,ids = skid
    Q0 = np.percentile(df[((df['sku'] == sku) & (df['ids'] == ids)), 0)
    Q4 = np.percentile(df[((df['sku'] == sku) & (df['ids'] == ids))], 100)
    return (sku,ids,Q0,Q4)

for data in pool.imap(multi_processing_tuples,tup):
    dfsi.append(data)
```

Doing this will return the data from multi_processing_tuples, but you should probably also pass `df` in as an argument.

EDIT: Also, you should generally not use threads for this; if you're trying to improve runtime on a CPU-intensive process, you should use a process pool. Threading will help with IO-intensive processes.

Comment: i am getting output as <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x19944ae3b38>, how do i resolve it?

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad. Fixed the answer to use imap instead. (`imap_async` might work better)